# Casting a date time from a datetimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetimepicker

I have an SQL query which should return some data between two dates that are selected using two datetime pickers, but when both the dates are equal it should return the data for that day instead. My query doesn't return anything as my date is in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` format. I use the following date format from my datetime picker

```
dtpEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

For example when my end date is 4/13/2014 then it returns the data which is before `4/13/2014 00:00:00` but I would like the data until `4/13/2014 23:59:59`

I have the following query

```
SELECT   
  sum(isnull(ExpectedAmt, 0)) AS Payment  FROM  Sales                            
  WHERE  (a.SellDate >= @StartDate)  AND (a.SellDate <= @EndDate)
```

I tried casting the data time but was not able to convert it to date time type. Is there any better way I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the `Date` part of the datetime is the same. If so, adjust the values accordingly

```
if(firstDate.Date.Equals(secondDate.Date))
{
    firstDate = firstDate.Date; 
         //If any time of day was set, it's now 0:00:00

    secondDate = firstDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1); 
         //This is now the day with time 23:59:59
}
```

At that point, you can continue your regular filtering.

Comment: If you want to ALWAYS get all the transactions that happened on the seconddate, I wouldn't bother with the check for equality, check if the seconddate is 0:00:00 and if so do the same addday addseconds fix

Comment: @Talspaugh27: It's a good general tip, but it's not in scope of the current question, if I read it correctly (I don't always :)) It could very well be that at some point or other, the Time part gets cut off (since OP seems to be using >= operators). Which renders my answer rather useless, but since it wasn't mentioned specifically, I can't know that :)

Comment: I was working off of this line "For example when my end date is 4/13/2014 then it returns the data which is before 4/13/2014 00:00:00 but I would like the data until 4/13/2014 23:59:59"

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL database is MS SQL Server, you can use the DATEDIFF function. Your SQL fails because both your DateTime objects have 0 hours/minutes/seconds and the data in your table presumably don't.

`DATEDIFF(DAY, date1, date2) <= 0` is true if date1 is later than or the same as date2, ignoring any unit of time smaller than a day.